# How to upload images without page reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I've got a php function which uploading images in my folder images:

```js
if(isset($_FILES['filename']))
{
 $Dest = dirname(__FILE__).'/images/';
 if(!isset($_FILES['filename']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][0]))
 {
 die('Something went wrong with Upload!');
 }

 $ImageName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['filename']['name'][0]));
 $ImageType = $_FILES['filename']['type'][0]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.
 
 $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
 $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
 
 $ImageName = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);

 //Create new image name (with random number added).
 $NewName = $ImageName.'.'.$ImageExt;
 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][0], "$Dest/$NewName");
 $base_path="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 $base=$base_path.'/'.'images/'.$NewName;
 ?>
 <script>
 window.history.back();
</script>
 <?php
}
```

here is my form:

```html
<form action="images.php" ng-show="data.uploadFile"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fileupload" id="fileupload">
 <input name="filename[]" id="filename" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" ng-click="data.uploadFile = !data.uploadFile" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and finally this is my Js code to get all images from folder:

```js
sliders.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$interval', '$http', function($scope, $interval, $http) {

 $scope.data = {uploadFile: false};

 //variables for slider #1
 $scope.timer1;
 $scope.index1 = 0;
 
 //variables for slider #2
 $scope.timer2;
 $scope.index2 = 0;
 

 $http.get('images.php').success(function(data) {
  $scope.images = data.split(',');
  $scope.images.pop();
 }); //get array with images and put in $scope.images
```

I'm using angularJs, and actually i can't understand how can i use angular or AJAX to upload images without reloading page, for example, if i will use in my form, some js function instead of action="images.php", how then will work php upload function?

I will appreciate if somebody explain me how can i do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

images.phpYou can try this code:

In your HTML:

```
/* Add id parameter to form */
<form id="form-id" action="images.php" ng-show="data.uploadFile"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fileupload" id="fileupload">
    <input name="filename[]" id="filename" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" ng-click="data.uploadFile = !data.uploadFile" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

In your JS:

```
/* Prevent submit and send by Ajax Call */
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#form-id').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'images.php',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

Update:

I added "processData" and "contentType" parameters to Ajax Call.

Comment: here in url :  'url: 'http://your.server.com/path/','
it should be path to my php file?

Comment: yes, "url" is the same value that "action" in form, in this case "images.php", changed in reply.

Comment: Unfortunately happens error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: sorry i'm mistaken, please wait until i'm check the answer.

Comment: Ok, try adding processData and contentType parameters to ajax call, the sample is updated.

Comment: Now error is gone, it works, but i still have to reload page, if i won't i could not see new image in my slider, i've got slider in my page, and i should to upload new pictures in time when slider works, without page reloading, maybe you know how i can dynamically put new picture in my $scope.images variable?
Anyway thank you for your help and spent time:)

Comment: No, in "success" parameter you can add your image in the slider using javascript, i don't write it this part of code because i don't know how is your slider. You can reply the url in image.php response and then, in success parameter add a `$('#slider').append('<img src=" '+data.url+' " />');` or similar something

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugin available for file upload without page loading and show image preview it self. I have listed plugins with demo link here..

1. [**dropzone**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html)
2. **[Bootstrap file upload](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo)**